# Can TRIM function in SQL be more precise?

Tags: sql, postgresql, trim

I have an import table that I want to split into other tables. There's a column in the import table which the data of it's fields have this format: `['email', 'phone', 'facebook']`.

In order to separate each value on the field (email, phone and facebook in this case) I'm using the function TRIM when I insert into it's corresponding table, like this:

```
insert into Media (media)
select distinct trim ('{}' from regexp_split_to_table(host_media, ','))
from ImportH;
```

But the data inserted into the new table looks dirty, for example in row 1 I would have `['email'`, in row 2: `'phone'` and in row 3: `'facebook']`.

How can I make it so the data inserts into the table in a clean way, without the '[' and the floating commas?

I'll provide an image of the import table data of this column and what I get when I split it:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Doesn't Postgres have JSON and ARRAY functions to query this without doing all this awful data splitting and manipulation?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I'm asking. Thanks for the info, I'll search it up

Comment: This is not valid JSON though.

Comment: Ah well, string splitting it is. Looks like Gordon has you covered.

Comment: If you want to trim `[]` you should probably specify this, and not `{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just change the splitter:

```
select *
from regexp_split_to_table('[''email'', ''phone'', ''facebook'']', '[^_a-zA-Z]+') s(value)
where value <> '';
```

The splitters are just whatever characters are NOT valid characters for the strings you want.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ca467a9f2a2a1313022f5edb36dc7162) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Still built on a guess. Why not go with something more safe as  `^\[''|''\s*,\s*''|'']$`?

Answer (score 0):

One of the options... Maybe it will be ok for you:

```
with trimed as
(select substring(host_media from 2 for length(host_media)-2) as clean_col
from ImportH
)
insert into Media (media)
select unnest(string_to_array(clean_col, ',')) 
from trimed;
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6bd2e4ba7b11f5a8b1b622f9cb178be3)

I have understood the "floating commas" term little bit late so I added some changes to my query:

```
with trimed as
(select replace(substring(host_media from 2 for length(host_media)-2), '''', '') as clean_col
 from ImportH
)
insert into Media (media)
select ltrim(unnest(string_to_array(clean_col, ','))) 
from trimed;
```

Comment: You're assuming that comma is always an element separator

Comment: Hi @DavidדודוMarkovitz It is not ?

Comment: The fact that the values are quoted makes it a risky guess

Comment: I have seen examples from OP. All have commas.

Comment: A separator is always comma, it doesn't mean that every comma is a separator

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach which uses json functions.

First create media table;

```
CREATE TABLE media AS (
  WITH my_medias AS (
    SELECT
        jsonb_array_elements_text(jsonb_agg(DISTINCT medias ORDER BY medias)) media
      FROM impor_th, jsonb_array_elements_text(replace(host_media, '''', '"')::jsonb) medias
  )
  SELECT
      row_number() OVER () media_id,
      *
    FROM my_medias
);
```

Then create many-to-many relation table;

```
CREATE TABLE media_host AS (
  WITH elements AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        jsonb_array_elements_text(replace(host_media, '''', '"')::jsonb) media
      FROM impor_th i
  )
  SELECT
      e.id AS impor_th_id,
      m.media_id
    FROM elements e
    JOIN media m ON m.media = e.media
);
```